# How merge two angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im working with one example to add search/filter functionality to Angular table. Have this code but not sure what does:

I have two controller.

- **eventCtrl:** Is already working, allow me to get the data from db. create `$scope.cars` and display in the angular table. I want to change so also include the filter functionality.
- **filteredTableCtrl :** is the one used on the example. Is working ok on the **[sample](http://samu.github.io/angular-table/examples/examples.html)** and I trying to merge that code with my controler also need some changes because will search for multiple field.

**filteredTableCtrl :**

1. has some values between `[ .. ]`, dont know what are those for, my version doesnt use that sintaxis.
2. this version has `$filter` mine need `$http` to get the data from server how I merge both?.
3. I search for `"filter"` but didnt find it, so not sure what functionality add to the filter.
4. `$scope.list` is the original list and `#scope.query` is the search input text model. That part I understand
5. But why comment the other function `$scope.getList()`

--

```
var app5 = angular.module("angular-table-example").controller("filteredTableCtrl", 
               ["$scope", "$filter", function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.list = $scope.$parent.personList;
    $scope.filteredList = $scope.list;

    // $scope.getList = function() {
    //   return $filter("filter")($scope.list, $scope.query);
    // }

    $scope.del = function (i) {
        console.log("index: " + i);
        $scope.list.splice(i, 1);
        $scope.updateFilteredList();
    }

    $scope.updateFilteredList = function () {
        $scope.filteredList = $filter("filter")($scope.list, $scope.query);
    };

}])
```

This is my code and is already working. Already can use `$scope.cars` to show the result from db in the table.

**eventCtrl:**

7. What is the sintaxis to add `$filter`
8. How I call the  `$scope.updateFilteredList` to update the list after new data arrive.
9. what is `"filter"`

--

```
app5.controller('eventCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    // create a dummy object so the table doesnt give js errors
    // dont know if there is a better way to do this.
    $scope.cars = [
        { Car_ID: null, X: null, Y: null, 
          RoadName: null, Azimuth: null, DateTime: null, 
          Adress: null }
    ];

    // want add the filtered list like the other controller
    $scope.filteredList = $scope.cars;

    // but dont have $filter and dont know what is 'filter'
    $scope.updateFilteredList = function () {
        $scope.filteredList = $filter("filter")($scope.cars, $scope.filter_id);
    };

    // this is working fine until i try add the filtered list.
    $http.get('getCars')
       .then(function (res) {
           $scope.cars = res.data;
           // how call the filtered function here?
           $scope.filteredList = $filter("filter")($scope.cars, $scope.filter_id);
       });

});
```

Comment: can you make the question clearer?  what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: @MB Im trying to understand the sample to filter rows on my table using angular. But are several question.

Comment: is the list to filter loaded when the controller initializes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Angular needs to know what are you injecting, when you minify your code, the variables like $scope and $filter are changed to 'a' or 'b'. Without those ['$scope', '..'], angular would not know what to inject into 'a' and 'b'. It's not needed if you don't minify.
2. You can inject both $http and $filter in your controller if needed.
3. $filter in angular mutate data. Filter inside this controller is filtering the list with the data from the query. (I'm not sure exactly what you want here)
4. OK
5. Because it is not being used, probably.

---

7. Just add $filter after '$scope, $http'.
8. You don't need to, the filtered list is already being updated after the data arrived (inside the '.then(function...'). If you want to:

```js
 $http.get('getCars')
  .then(function (res) {
     $scope.cars = res.data;
     $scope.updateFilteredList();
  });
```

9. Filter does exactly that, filters a value accordingly to a given query. Check the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Comment: I think you miss the number on last couple of item.  7 should be 8. I dont want repeat the code that is why I create the function. But couldnt call it inside my `$htpp` request

Comment: Change $scope.filteredList = $filter("filter")($scope.cars, $scope.filter_id); to  $scope.updateFilteredList();

Comment: Added a snippet for the 8

Comment: Any chance you know how change the filter to work just in a column? right now search on every field. Would like to include multiple filters/columns.

Comment: You can apply a filter in the <td> tags. Like <td> {{row.name | uppercase}} </td> where uppercase is the filter.

Comment: Ok, I will try, but dont know if that will affect the `pager`. I think I should filter on the collection `$scope.filteredList`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118948/discussion-between-tpsilva-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Answer (score 1):

I think the first point is what you really need an explanation for. The syntax being used for dependencies is [inline array notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#injection-function-annotation), which is a way of ensuring Angular knows what dependencies you're asking for, even if your JS gets minified.

It takes the form of an array containing any number of strings (each being the name of a dependency you need), followed by your controller function, which takes parameters to match the dependencies (!! in the same order as the array listed them !!).

Example:

```
app5.controller('eventCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$filter', function ($scope, $http, filter) {

    $http.get(/* Do whatever HTTP stuff you want here*/)
        .then(function(results){
            $scope.filteredList = $filter("filter")($scope.list, $scope.query);
            //Or do whatever you want to do with the results
        });

} //End of controller function
] /*End of the dependency array*/)
```